# Add Customized Machine Key to Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, system-configuration

I have 2 application one in MVC 5 and another on asp.net core 2.2

I have added Machine Key On MVC 5 under system.web like below

```
<machineKey
 validationKey="0C0D6B2776BE432EE3B1554D5C8F88C168944B7E9B7A0FFC885DDE9E9AFA093A"
 decryptionKey="09CCCB69B54D74DB1C2379AB13371EA3D6743227BE6E0092EA3FB762D53668A6"
 validation="SHA1"
 decryption="AES"
 />
```

I want to apply the same key for .net core. I found some link to use data protection but I failed to add these keys to that.

Is there any way we can apply the key to the asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

> I want to apply the same key for .net core. I found some link to use data protection but I failed to add these keys to that.

ASP.NET Core doesn't use `web.config`, and even if it did, it doesn't use machine keys either. Cryptography is handled via the [Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which stores and generates keys in an entirely different way.

If you need to share things like [cookies between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you have to work in the opposite way and plug in the `Data Protection API` into your ASP.NET apps, so that they use the same system as ASP.NET Core.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Do you know any data protection API which I can use. My Main problem is I am using load balancing and Redis + SignalR for sharing data and I have disbaled sticky Session so I read that I have to same the machine key so I planned to implement liek above. My Asp.Net Signalr application working fine for multiple server but when I tried to send the message to asp.net core it doesnot work. Please suggest any good way to implement his

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know any data protection API which I can use. My Main problem is I am using load balancing and Redis + SignalR for sharing data and I have disbaled sticky Session so I read that I have to same the machine key so I planned to implement liek above. My Asp.Net Signalr application working fine for multiple server but when I tried to send the message to asp.net core it doesnot work. Please suggest any good way to implement his

It seems that you encrypted the message from a MVC 5, and want to decrypt the message from Asp.Net Core 2.2 application which is deploy on another machine. The [MachineKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.machinekey?view=netframework-4.8) is only supported under .NET Framework.

To encrypt/decrypt data cross the application framework, you need to use class which support both under .NET Framework and .Net Core. And you can refer it from .NET Standard(eg. [System.Security.Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netstandard-2.0)). Below is an demo to use [Aes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netstandard-2.0) crossing the console apps between .NET Framework and .Net Core:

**.Net Framework, console app encrypt data**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

        // Create a new instance of the Aes
        // class.  This generates a new key and initialization
        // vector (IV).
        using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("key.data", myAes.Key);
            File.WriteAllBytes("IV.data", myAes.IV);
            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
            File.WriteAllBytes("encrypted.data", encrypted);
            Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
        }

        return;
    }

   

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }
```

**.Net core console app, decrypt data**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
        //string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
   
        var key = File.ReadAllBytes("key.data");
        var iv = File.ReadAllBytes("IV.data");
        var encryptedData= File.ReadAllBytes("encrypted.data");
        // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
        string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encryptedData, key, iv);
 
        Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
    }



    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

And you can also refer to the link below for the details about target framework.

[Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-target-framework-versions)